# How can we automate Facebook Account Kit login for testing purpose?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, user-accounts, web-api-testing, account-kit

For normal Facebook login, we could use Facebook [Test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users), But these won't work with Account Kit. The tokens produced for Tests Users are not valid for Account kit. 
Is there any way through which we can generate a login token for Account Kit accounts without manual intervention, so that we can use it for our continuous API testing process?

Comment: My only solution is writing a script open email and click on the link